# Window height jquery function returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, height

$(window).height(); returns no values says its undefined.

```
                         var modalHeight = $(window).height();

                        $('.inside-body-wrapper').css("max-height",modalHeight);
                        $('.overlay').css("height",modalHeight);
                        $('.modal').css({
                            display: "block",
                            height: modalHeight
                        });
```

[image: Below is the screenshot of console.]

Comment: add your jquery inside `$(document).ready(function(){  your-code });`

Answer (score 1):

You can use..

```
$(document).ready(function() {     

  var wt = $(window).width();
  var ht = $(window).height();
  ....
  ....    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is clear if you think about what jquery actually does, it's returning the height style property for whatever you give the selector. As window doesn't have that it will be undefined.

You could instead try using window.outerHeight or window.innerHeight to get those properties instead which could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can make you body tag 100% height and after get the height of the body not the height of the window.